# Windows 10 Upgrade failure from windows 8.1

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have been attempting to upgrade Windows from 8.1 to 10 and so far it failed at various stages, with the screen becoming unresponsive and black.

After reading various comments I have attempted the below:

- Uninstalled & Removed Avast antivirus
- Disabled Firewall
- Removed Nvidia Graphic card (asus) and uninstalled any software associated with it
- Updated Intel Graphic drivers (they were outdated)
- Run the Microsoft Windows update troubleshooter. This apparently fixed problem 0x80070057, 'service registration missing or corrupt' and 'problems installing recent updates'.
- Uninstalled all unnecessary programs
- Disabled all startup programs
- Removed all unnecessary USB connections

The maximum percentage of upgrade completion that I saw before the PC froze was 88% after possibly more than a dozen attempts. The PC has been left in the 'black screen' frozen status for more than 8 hours, just to be sure that the update was not interrupted.

When the PC freezes there is zero disc activity and no device (mouse, keyboard) is recognized.

A force restart results in 3, 4 restarts where initially the system tries to restore the update and then - thankfully - reverts to the previous installed version (8.1) with no issue.

Now the PC is from Zoostorm, but the automatic test carried out from the Microsoft Windows 10 confirm that Windows 10 App should work on the machine with no issue.

Any suggestion to resolve this?

So far it's been a disappointing experience, especially as the error messages provided are completely vague in truly Microsoft style.

Happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: Do you have any faulty hardware? Im note sure if it is a windows update problem. Your computer may freeze because your HDD or other components have an issue.
In general uninstall all software that may access some "deep" part of your OS like antivir, backup software like acronis true image.

Comment: Hi Ivan thanks but this is unlikely. The HDD is in perfect form and as mentioned in the description, I have uninstalled already antivirus. Not sure what else should be uninstalled. Also 'other components' it's a bit vague. I stress that the machine is in perfect functioning state.

Comment: Then we need some point where we can start. Look for the file "windowsupdate.log" located in C:\windows\ open the file and scroll down untill the file ends. Check if the date and time of the last entry. If the date and time is near the time you tried to update to windows 10 we need to analyze the content. If we need to analyze it this link will may help https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/902093

Comment: I have located and checked the windowsupdate.log file, I have logs for yesterday and today. In no chronological order: 2015-08-09 12:32:57:708  340 16bc Report WARNING: CSerializationHelper:: InitSerialize failed : 0x80070002
2015-08-09 12:32:57:708  340 16bc Report WARNING: CSerializationHelper:: InitSerialize failed : 0x80070002

2015-08-09 08:07:58:478  404 f08 EP FATAL: Failed to obtain plugin interfaces using CLSID 7D5F3CBA-03DB-4BE5-B4B3-6DBED19A6833, error = 0x8024000E

Comment: there is more in the file as you can guess. After the current update will fail again, I will get down and uninstall more applications to see if this has an effect.

Comment: You will need to google the error codes and try out the sugested solutions and then try to install windows 10 again. Just be aware that this may not help at all but you need some imput to get a direction what the problem is. Maybe there is a own log for the windows 10 update? After a failed update try a search for all changed files in the last hours.

Comment: After another failed install - and removing of other programs - error C1900101-40017 was returned. I will check if the  advise given in [link](http://bit.ly/1IvU6fO) will be of any help.

Comment: About previous comment I have tried 'method 2' but no joy. I am now making the last attempt by using the media creation tool with DVD ( http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install ). I will add a final comment as an answer to this thread with the result.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution by answering your own question. We don't add "solved" on the Super User Q&A, but instead "accept" an answer; see http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have used the installation via media creation tool with DVD but again the result was the infamous black screen with the arrow pointer in the middle and system frozen.

After speaking with the PC manufacturer, I have performed the PC '[Refresh](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc)'. This uninstall ALL user installed software and revert the machine to factory settings. Note that data (documents, photos etc. )is untouched by this process.

The Refresh meant that the operating system was reverted to Windows 8. I had to upgrade to Windows 8.1. In addition I had to reinstall ALL the Windows updates to date.

After all updates were installed - note that it can take quite a few restart/check for updates - **it was eventually possible to complete the upgrade successfully**.

This seems to validate what error 0xC1900101 - 0x40017 is commonly associated with - non Microsoft software - causing the failure to upgrade.

Nonetheless, quite a painful process for an upgrade. Hope this will help some of the many users affected.